# Show errors: can't have a read access on a specific object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

We are using sql server 2016 and i try to have a view on "connections" and "read access denied" error.

Could you please tell me if you know a way to show login attempts (and accessed object in error) **from management studio**? (maybe a sys table or a dmv)

**I have sysadmin rights on sql server but no access on the machine, then i can't show windows log.**

Thank you for your help,

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

I found my response.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Gwb.png)

We can show our Windows and SQL Server log from management studio:

[image: SQL Server Logs]
Thank you,
Arnaud